# Make terminal open a file with default editor

Tags: git, unix, terminal

Is there a way I can say open file.php in the terminal and have jEdit open the file.php? Now I have to go to a finder window and find the file...which there are too many files and the order of the files keeps changing even though I specify by name.

Note: I am working on a remote server. I login via ssh and am using a git repository. I want to be able to bring back the file on the remote server to my jEdit window on my machine. When I save it on my machine it is saved on the remote server.

Comment: Try asking this question on superuser. (And take a look at `ssh -X`.)

Answer (score 0):

You didin't say which distro you are using. Try

```
gnome-open file.php
```

BTW this question should be in superuser.

Comment: I'm actually logged in to a local server...I want to open the html files in my jEdit and edit them there directly instead of using vi...

I know I can open the files in jEdit if I use my finder window (I'm logged into local server) or if I login using sftp with Cyberduck.

I was just wondering if there is a way to hook it up so I can say a command in the terminal and it would open up in jEdit without me navigating to find the files.

Comment: the information that you are working on a remote server completely changes the question...

Answer (score 0):

If you're on KDE, use `kde-open some-file.php`. For Gnome, it's `gnome-open some-file.php`. You have to set jEdit as default editor for .php files through KDE's or Gnome's configuration facilities for this to work, though.

edit: On OS X, it's simply `open some-file.php`

Comment: Since he is talking about a “finder window”, I suppose he’s using neither KDE nor Gnome. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write something like

```
jedit file.php
```

in the terminal. See [the jEdit documentation](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/cli-usage.html) for more information.